# Melding operation in Weight biased leftist tree

Tags: c

I need help with implement of the melding operation in Weight Biased Leftist Tree in C Coding

the Psuedo code can also be done but prefer C coding. :D

The melding operation in Weight Biased Leftist Tree should be done in a single top to bottom pass (not recursive)

Right now I have this

```
   int main() 
   {
        double wi1, ci1, wi2, ci2, result;

        printf("Weight - Item1: ");
        scanf("%lf", &wi1);

        printf("No. of item1: ");
        scanf("%lf", &ci1);

        printf("Weight - Item2: ");
        scanf("%lf", &wi2);

        printf("No. of item2: ");
        scanf("%lf", &ci2);

        result = ((wi1 * ci1) + (wi2 * ci2)) / (ci1 + ci2);
        printf("Average Value = %f\n", result);

        return 0;
    }
```

just checking if this is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure to what your question exactly refers, but in terms of C-Code your example looks functional. Yet you may want to check out sscanf function for a safer way to read in stuff and maybe think about input checking your values.

Another issue might be, that your code only works on two values in total. Assuming you want to have larger numbers, you need to redesign your code to loop over those values. This can be done without recursion.

For the maths behind this I only see a normal average calculation, not sure if this is, what you intended.

Comment: in order to code the looping over the values, what should I do?

Comment: Well, as wi1 and wi2 as well as ci1 and ci2 are of the same type you can collect them into arrays and then easily extend those arrays to the maximum number of elements, you want to digest. So you end up with wi[] and ci[].
Then you would set up your input to loop as long as you enter new value pairs.
After the input "phase" is done, you start the calculation, where you need to rewrite  your formula to handle all elements of the array correctly.
You could mix those to phases, but that would add a little more complexity, therefore doing one after the other should be fine.

Comment: Ps: The lack of code examples in my previous answer is intended as you're supposed to try it on your own and come back with new questions, if you get stuck.
Anyway it looks like a neat little coding task for me, so enjoy the work. ;)